# MFC modeless dialog box and edit control

Tags: mfc

Ihave a modeless dialog with (relevant to this discussion) an edit control where users input data and an 'Apply' button that is disabled unless valid data is supplied to the aforementioned edit control.

The problem is that being a modeless dialog, hitting the enter key in the edit control doesn't kill focus and hence doesn't trigger the `ON_EN_KILLFOCUS` message notification associated with the edit control which validates the input and potentially enables the apply button. Currently users have to click away from the modeless dialog to trigger `ON_EN_KILLFOCUS`.

Is there a way to make it so that validation can be triggered without the user having to remove focus from the dialog? Usually with modal dialogs the enter key triggers `ON_EN_FOCUS` and that's what I'm used to.

I've tried using `ON_EN_CHANGE` but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why overcomplicate it? Handle `EN_CHANGE` since this means the content had changed. At this point change the Apply button to enabled. Now the user can click it. Whats more, the Apply button can validate all the data and decide to proceed or not. No need to use focus handlers for this.

Comment: Hi I've tried using ON_EN_CHANGE but it doesn't get called when the text in the edit control gets modified

Comment: @stephenyou `ON_EN_CHANGE` works. There is something you've done wrong in some code you didn't show. You need to show at least the relevant parts of your code such as the message map, your `ON_EN CHANGE` handler and the dialog definition in the .rc  file. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: This is probably the issue you're running into: [Just because you're a control doesn't mean that you're necessarily inside a dialog box](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070820-00/?p=25513).

Answer (score 1):

The Enter key is handled in `PreTranslateMessage` and in fact the control doesn't loose the focus. The hit of the enter key is handles before the control receives any keyboard input.

So maybe the easiest way to handle all cases us `OnChange` (`EN_CHANGE') to track any change. If this is to complicated. Handle PreTranslateMessage and track the` VK_ENTER`key`WM_KEYDOWN` message and execute your validation code before passing the message to the default handler.

Comment: I've tried using ON_EN_CHANGE but it doesn't trigger when the text in the edit control gets changed.

Comment: Wrong Control Id?
Show us more code.